# Is there a possibility to introduce packet loss and delay in AWS between IGW and a EC2 Router, which needs to have public IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way, to introduce delay and packet loss for network testing, between a router which needs to have a public IP outgoing in direction of IGW?

If I could use private IPs, than I could us a linux host between, but this is unfortunately not possible, because of IPSec an NAT!???

One solution could be to do a 1:1 NAT from Linux to the Router and assign the EIP to the Linux host!???

Comment: Yes, you can use NAT instance, instead of NAT gateway.

Comment: And how I can introduce packet loss there?